# Is there a way to make Google Calendar behave more like 30boxes.com?

Tags: google-calendar

On [30boxes.com](http://30boxes.com) they show 4 weeks at a time (possibly spanning two months) and as you navigate the view shifts by one week at a time.  Is there a way to make Gmail show 4 weeks at a time and still allow me to move by one-week intervals?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, however, you could go into settings and use the custom view to see if any of them are suitable.  For example, you can choose to show 2, 3 or 4 weeks instead of a month.  Keep an eye on their 'Labs' tab in settings as they put experimental features in there (such as year-view).

Comment: This seems pretty close. While it doesn't allow you to advance the view 1 week at a time, displaying 4 weeks at a time starting from the current week is a great improvement. I'm going to start doing this!